# Pandas groupby() and agg() ignore errors

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

UPDATED for completeness:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.to_datetime(['2017-10-01','2017-10-02','2017-10-03']).tolist()

df = pd.DataFrame({ 
            'day_of_week':['m','t','w'],
            'alpha':[1,2,3],
            'bravo'[4,5,6],
            'charlie':[7,8,9],
            'dates':dates
            })

agg_dik = {'alpha': sum,
           'bravo': sum,
           'charlie': max,
           'dates': sum}

df = df.groupby('day_of_week').agg(agg_dik).reset_index(drop = True)
```

And this throws an error on the sum of the datetimes.  So I can avoid that if the dataframe truly has five columns, but I have dataframes with hundreds of columns and often build aggregate dictionary comprehensions like:

```
agg_dik = { c : max if 'e' in c else sum for c in cols }
```

However, when the `groupby().agg()` hits a series where sum is not allowed, it errors out.

**So my question - is there a way to achieve the results I'm looking for but have pandas either drop the erroring columns or replace with NaN and continue on?**

I've looked at a few other questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039923/standard-error-ignoring-nan-in-pandas-groupby-groups)), but they don't fully answer my question.

Comment: Given that you are not telling us why and how the `sum` and `mean` functions are failing, your best bet is to write custom `sum_` and `mean_` functions that use `try-except` statements in them to catch the cases when an error is produced.

Comment: @Abdou - I've narrowed the issue down to the `sum` of `datetimes` only.  But I think the question still remains.  Would the try-except within a function (ostensibly a loop), not defeat the purpose of using the `.agg()` function in the first place?

Comment: You're not looping. Something like `def sum_(x): try: return sum(x) except: return np.nan` is what I am thinking about?

Comment: Ok.  If you want to put together a full answer, I'll try it out and accept if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues at hand:

1. Your dictionary of functions may contain columns that are not in the dataframe you're working with. In cases like that you will need to grab only the elements whose keys match the columns present in the dataframe.
2. Some of your functions throw errors/exceptions that need to be caught. Otherwise, that list line of your code will not work.

The following is a solution that should handle these two cases:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.to_datetime(['2017-10-01','2017-10-02','2017-10-03'])

df = pd.DataFrame({ 
            'day_of_week': ['m','t','w'],
            'alpha': [1,2,3],
            'bravo': [4,5,6],
            'charlie': [7,8,9],
            'dates':dates
            })

def sum_(x):
    try:
        return np.sum(x)
    except:
        return np.nan

def max_(x):
    try:
        return np.max(x)
    except:
        return np.nan

agg_dik = {'alpha': sum_,
           'bravo': sum_,
           'charlie': max_,
           'delta': max_}

df = df.groupby('day_of_week').agg({k:v for k,v in agg_dik.items() if k in df}).reset_index(drop = True)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - the `dates` --> `delta` thing was just a typo.  But if I make that correction, I'm still getting `NaN` on `charlie`, which I wouldn't expect.  The `dates` column does return `NaN`, which is great.  Fix was to add an `x` in the `np.max()` line and test by changing `max_` to `sum_` for `dates`.  All good, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for catching the missing `x`. I'm glad this helped.